# Facing IndexEntryConflictException while merging

Tags: neo4j

we are facing the `IndexEntryConflictException` error while executing the merge statement, however, it happens intermittently. can anyone please help resolve this?

Neo4j version - 4.0

```
{ timestamp: "2021-01-06T10:00:18.567Z",level: "error", message: "merge statement Neo4jError: Caused by: IndexEntryConflictException{propertyValues=( String("8781237720003455611") ), addedNodeId=-1, existingNodeId=59898}" }
```

Comment: 4.0.0 is an old version, and .0 releases are likely to have the most bugs compared to their subsequent patch releases. I'd recommend upgrading to the latest patch for your minor version (unless you want to upgrade to the latest minor version too) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the instance,
delete the `index` and `schema` directories,
then restart the instance.
It will solve the issue.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a more detailed explanation as to why deleting those folders would solve the issue? This is the only question related to this issue I've found online